# Typescript compiler type to class

Tags: typescript, compiler-construction

I'm working on the TypeScript compiler and have a type: I'm looking to get the class for the type: I was expecting a utiltity in checker.js or binder.ts called something like "classToType." I'll need a type for the actual class (nominal, not structural).

Is there such a utility? If not, any recommendation on how to do such a thing?

My overall goal is to force [private names](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-private-fields) to be nominal and non-inheritable, and this is an approach I'm trying. In pseudocode:

`in checker.js::getPropertyOfType:
        if the propery is a private name and the type is not the containing class:
            then return undefined`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getClassLikeDeclarationOfSymbol(type.symbol)`. That function is defined in `compiler/utilties.ts`.

But that's not the only way of achieving the goal of not allowing structural typing for classes with private names. Another is to check for a private name whenever adding a declaration to a symbol, adding a new SymbolFlag, and checking for the symbol flag in `getUnmatchedProperty`.